# keras custom ImageDataGenerator

Tags: python, keras

Is there anyway we can add some functionality to the ImageDataGenerator, so that the ImageDataGenerator can take a list of filenames, and random sample images for each minibatch?

I know that I can custom a class which inherit ImageDataGenerator class, but I still don't know the details how to do that.

Here is what I have done:

```
for epoch in range(epochs):
    print("epoch is: %d, total epochs: %f" % ((epoch+1), int(epochs)))
    print("prepare training batch...")
    train_batch = makebatch(filelist=self.train_files, img_num=img_num, slice_times=slice_times)
    print("prepare validation batch..")
    val_batch = makebatch(filelist=self.val_files, img_num=int(math.ceil(img_num*0.2)), slice_times=slice_times)

    x_train = train_batch
    y_train = x_train

    x_val = val_batch
    y_val = x_val

    print("generate training data...")

    train_datagen.fit(x_train)
    train_generator = train_datagen.flow(
        x=x_train,
        y=y_train,
        batch_size=16)
    val_datagen.fit(x_val)
    val_generator = val_datagen.flow(
        x=x_val,
        y=y_val,
        batch_size=16)

    print("start training..")

    history = model.fit_generator(
            generator=train_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=None,
            epochs=1,
            verbose=1,
            validation_data=val_generator,
            validation_steps=None,
            callbacks=self.callbacks)
```

what I really want to obtain is that I can remove the for loop and the generator random sample images for each batch.

Someone can help with that?

Comment: Do you have paths to all the images separated as training and validation?

Comment: no they are from the same path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, what I would do.

Suppose I have a list of paths to all images stored in variables X_train, X_validation and the labels are stored as  y_train and y_validation.

First, I would define a sequence generator. ( This is from keras website)

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.transform import resize
import numpy as np

# Here, `x_set` is list of path to the images
# and `y_set` are the associated classes.    

class CIFAR10Sequence(Sequence):    
    def __init__(self, x_set, y_set, batch_size):
        self.x, self.y = x_set, y_set
        self.batch_size = batch_size

    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.x) / float(self.batch_size)))

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        batch_x = self.x[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_y = self.y[idx * self.batch_size:(idx + 1) * self.batch_size]

        return np.array([
            resize(imread(file_name), (200, 200))
               for file_name in batch_x]), np.array(batch_y)
```

Now, I would define generator for training and validation as

```
Xtrain_gen = detracSequence(X_train,y_train,batch_size=512) # you can choose your batch size.
Xvalidation_gen = detracSequence(X_validation,y_validation,batch_size=512)
```

Now, final step to train the model

```
model.fit_generator(generator=Xtrain_gen, epochs=100, validation_data=Xvalidation_gen,use_multiprocessing=True)
```

This will avoid the for loop for you and it's very efficient because CPU fetch data in parallel.

Comment: I think this may be somehow related what I'm looking for. Because if I run my script it will run out of memory. But can we still use ImageDataGenerator? Because I want to use that to do the image data augmentation. But I hope to add a functionality to sample random data from a list of filepath for each batch.

Comment: and a question is that how do we set idx? is it random?

Comment: and how I can to add some functions after imread, I actually need to furthur process my images after image read. How can I use on_epoch_end?

Comment: I will answer one by one:

Comment: This will resolve your memory issue. Yes, idx is random.

Comment: Rather than returning the image and label batch directly, you can fetch the image within __get__method, do your transformations and then return it. Basically, no need to write a comprehension list.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this instruction. I'll try the method.

Comment: It works! Can you furthur explain why idx is random please? How is idx beed determined? And what does multiprocessing do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173293/discussion-between-talos1904-and-hao-chen).